# dpkg: error processing linux-generic unmet dependency error

Tags: 12.04, kernel, dpkg

`dpkg: error processing linux-generic`, un met dependency error when `sudo apt-get install -f`

```
Setting up linux-image-generic (3.2.0.60.71) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.58.69); however:
  Version of linux-image-generic on system is 3.2.0.60.71.
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 3.2.0.58.69); however:
  Version of linux-headers-generic on system is 3.2.0.60.71.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: @Stormvirux Not exactly. He doesn't seem to know what package is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, myself, that made it impossible to add or remove packages. Essentially, it was a broken package. If a broken dependency is the issue for you, try following these instructions to flush it out:

1. Run the command, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. This will return an error, but don't worry.
2. Look at the error from the previous command. It should list broken package(s). Type `sudo dpkg -r PACKAGE_NAME` to remove each one. Some will probably fail to be removed. Add them to a list.
3. Run `sudo dpkg --configure PACKAGE_NAME` for each package in your list. This should repair them and return no fatal errors.
4. Finally, run `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix dependencies.

Now, you should be able to install your kernel. If this version is for the channel you're on, this can be done with a simple, `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Good luck!